# Should the "laptop" option be selected for netbooks when installing Debian?

Tags: debian, system-installation, netbook

When installing Debian on an Eee PC netbook, the "Software selection" screen shows "Desktop environment" is selected by default, but not "Laptop".

[image]

As laptops are similar to netbooks, should I select "laptop" when installing Debian?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Laptop` task contains the following packages:

```
$ tasksel --task-packages laptop
wireless-tools
acpi-support
cpufrequtils
acpi
wpasupplicant
powertop
acpid
apmd
pcmciautils
pm-utils
anacron
avahi-autoipd
bluetooth
```

Wifi, CPU frequency scaling, ACPI, Bluetooth, etc. So yes, you probably want those things.